# closest tr selection in JQuery select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Hope someone can advise.

I'm facing small issue trying to add certain data into a `select` dropdown which is `<option>`  elements that I'm fetching it with `Ajax` after clicking the check box in same `td` in a table.

Html:

```
<td class="col-lg-4"><select name="name[]" class="form-control name"></select>
```

Now the JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.check_box', function(){
            var name = $(this).data('name');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/someactionhere/',
                data:{name:name},
                success: function(data){
                    $(this).closest('tr').find('.name').html(data);
                }
            });

});
```

I know it's should be real simple but and looks like right to me. So I don't no if something wrong or not.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any `$(this)` inside `success`? Try to write it into console. In my view, there is another scope and `$(this)` isn't the same as on line 2.

Comment: it says: `context: undefined`

Comment: So, it's answer to your question. I'm so good in jQuery, maybe st. like `var elem = $(this)` on line 3? Maybe add any element identicator to called URL?

Comment: I think you can just change `success: function(data){` to `success: (data) => {`.

Comment: I tried before to print the data using `id` and this is worked actually but I don't want to print the data with id cause it may cause a conflict.

Comment: @Rocky Sims there is nothing wrong in my ajax code it's completely right the issue here on calling the closest tr with class `name` to print the `data` there.

Comment: You want to use an arrow function so that `$(this)` in `$(this).closest('tr')` still refers to the same element as when you use `$(this)` above in `var name = $(this).data('name');`.

Comment: Alternately you could do `const self = this;` just above `$.ajax({` and then instead of `$(this).closest('tr').find('.name').html(data);` do `$(self).closest('tr').find('.name').html(data);`.

Comment: @Rocky Sims I tried to use `var ref = $(this)` then `ref.closest....` inside the success but still nothing happen.

Comment: Still not working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ajax function, $(this) refers to the ajax function object, not the element that was clicked. To refer to that element, you need to first store it in a variable, like the comments suggest.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.check_box', function() {
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    let elem = $(this)
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
        data: {
            name: name
        },
        success: function(data) {
            elem.closest('tr').find('.name').html("<option>here is the html</option>");
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-lg-4">
      <input type='checkbox' data-name='test' class='check_box' />
      <select name="name[]" class="form-control name">
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer is absolutely right and make sense to me. But also not working, I'm confused I'm sure there is nothing wrong in my code.

Comment: I'm guessing that the `data` passed to the success handler doesn't begin/end with `<option>`/`</option>`.

Comment: @Rocky Sims yes it is.

Comment: Yes that's the problem or yes it is wrapped in an option tag?

Comment: No no. I already deleted before trying this answer. But wait the check box not inside the same `td` it's in another `td`

Comment: that part doens't matter. It is reaching out to find the closest TR tag. Are you sure you're getting a success response from your ajax?

Comment: Yes am sure. I already mentioned before, that when trying to get the response using the `id` it comes with no issue.